# How to add tool tip for image in Drupal? Using custom template

Tags: php, image, drupal, tooltip, cck

I'm using Drupal 6.x. This is my code on my node-product.tpl.php template. I've created a custom jquery gallery for the products. It works great, but I'm just missing tool tips from my images (both large and small thumbnails). To upload images I'm using a CCK field named field_images. There I input the image titles when I upload the images. How can I add the tool tip code snippet to make it work?

```
<div class="product-large">
<img src="/sites/default/files/imagecache/360x280/<?php print $node->field_images[0]['filename']; ?>" />
</div>

<div class="product-small">
   <?php
           // get all images
            foreach ($node->field_images as $images) {
        ?>
   <img src="/sites/default/files/imagecache/120x90/<?php print $images['filename']; ?>" rel="/sites/default/files/imagecache/360x280/<?php print $images['filename']; ?>" />
    <?php   
        }
        ?>
</div>
```

Thanks much appreciated!

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "tooltip" is a result of the `title` HTML attribute.  You'll want to add `title="foo"` to your `img` tag.

Perhaps:
`<img src="/sites/default/files/imagecache/120x90/<?php print $images['filename']; ?>" rel="/sites/default/files/imagecache/360x280/<?php print $images['data']['filename']; ?>" title="<?php print $images['title']; ?>"/>` for the second image and similarly `$node->field_images[0]['data']['title']` for the first.

Comment: This doesn't work when I add it to the top php snippet under "product-large".

title="<?php print $node->field_images[data]['title']; ?>"

It just outputs title=""

Comment: Try `$node->field_images[0]['data']['title']`.  Also make sure you quote 'data'.  Let me know and I will update my answer to match.

Comment: If you wouldn't mind and could spare a bit of time.. could you explain the why my code was wrong?

Comment: The second image tag is within the `for` loop that loops through the `field_images` array.  The first `img` tag is not and so you are manually indexing to the first element of the array, apparently the full-sized image in this case.  The `for` loop is basically auto-indexing for you which is why it is omitted in the second `img` tag.